# Android: How to list all the sub folder inside a parent folder?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

I want to show sub folder in my android app. How can I get the path of all the sub folders inside a parent folder. Let's say I have a folder named `Parent folder` and inside it is Two sub folder named `Sub Folder 1` and `Sub Folder 2` how can I get the path of this two sub folders in an array list?

Comment: `Let's say I have a folder named Parent folder ` Not enough. You should start with full path of thet folder.

Comment: What if the sub folder has a child sub folder in it? What is the required depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
To list all sub files and sub directories nested in all levels, one solution is to use recursion algorithm:
```

1. List files in the first level.
2. For each file in the first level list files:

a-If the file is a directory:

- Print out directory name.
- Repeat the step 1 and 2 with the current directory.

b-If the file is a file:

- Print out file name.
- Continue with next file.

Example code:

```
public void listDirectory(String dirPath, int level) {
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        File[] firstLevelFiles = dir.listFiles();
        if (firstLevelFiles != null && firstLevelFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File aFile : firstLevelFiles) {
                for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                    System.out.print("\t");
                }
                if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("[" + aFile.getName() + "]");
                    listDirectory(aFile.getAbsolutePath(), level + 1);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(aFile.getName());
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: In this Function what is the level parameter?

Comment: level:  is used to indent the output, make the output looks like a hierarchical structure. The method must be invoked with the level = 0.
As you can see, inside the listDirectory() method, there is a call to itself:
 listDirectory(aFile.getAbsolutePath(), level + 1);

Comment: Is there any way @Hieu? I don't wanna use 2 for